# Execute table2 query when it has null value in table1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables called warehouse table and order table.

```
Warehouse table (table1)
Customer   orderno 
 AA          111
 BB          222

Order table  (table2)
 Customer   orderno  status
 AA          111      1
 BB          222      2
 CC          333      3
 DD          444      4
```

My requirement is to show if any order is not available in table1 then it should select from table2 with status of (1,2,4)

I am trying with union but the results are not showing as expected.

````
    select customer,orderNo from table1 
    union 
    select customer,orderno from table2
    where status IN (1,2,4) ```

Can you please help me on this.
````

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect, as tabular text.

Comment: The union ought to do what you are describing. There must be a detail that you're leaving out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want orders with status of (1,2,4) then use below query

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.orderno = t2.orderno)
and t2.status IN (1,2,4)
order by status;
```

Comment: Hi Ravi Matani, Thank for the response.some of the orders are not showing.  Example: 111 order is available in table 1 and table2 but this 111 order is not showing  in the results.

Answer (score 0):

you can union the tables, prioritize the results and then get the one with the higher priority for each order.

```
    select Customer, orderno
from (
select Customer, orderno, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Customer, orderno order by Priority asc) as rn
from   (
select Customer, orderno, 1 as Priority from #table1
union all
select Customer, orderno, 2 as Priority  from #table2 where status IN (1,2,4)) o
) n
where n.rn = 1
```